# Vue search filter checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have problem with checkboxes and vue filter of array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript"},
      { text: "Learn Vue"},
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle"},
      { text: "Build something awesome"}
    ],
    search: '',
  },
  methods: {
   
  },
  computed: {
   filtered() {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => {
        return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="search">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in filtered">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox">

        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

If you check first from array and search for any of others:

Check -> Learn javascript

Search -> Learn Vue

Vue appear to be checked..

Is that suppose to work like that?

How can I remove all from displayed list and append same time?

Comment: Vue apears to be checked because of vue's optimization. Use v-model for each checkbox to avoid that.

Comment: Can you produce a working example?

Comment: The real question is, why is this happening, I'm also curious.

Comment: @Deda Because of vue's optimization proccess. It uses virtual DOM to do as little changes to DOM as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `v-model` to bind in `filtered` array

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript"},
      { text: "Learn Vue"},
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle",done:true},
      { text: "Build something awesome"}
    ],
    search: '',
  },
  methods: {
   
  },
  computed: {
   filtered() {
      return this.todos.filter(todo => {
        return todo.text.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
      })
    },
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="search">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="todo in filtered">
      <label>
        <input v-model="todo.done" type="checkbox">
          <del v-if="todo.done">{{ todo.text }}</del>
          <span v-if="!todo.done">{{ todo.text }}</span>
          
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Here is put checked by default for `Play around in JSFiddle`

Comment: This works but, I am fetching 'todos' as data from database.... I need to append additional field for each...

Comment: @Learner : what additional field ? can you share ?

Comment: That one for v model, like when I return data I return id, name and in todos array i have objects with id and name and for each I need to add done for v model

Comment: can you add this in your question so that we can understand better.

Comment: you answered my question and it works, but I need to add custom field for each result from database for v-model, or to add it on client side but I need to go throught all and add like: todo[done] = false or something like that, seems like too much work for something like this...

Comment: Oh I didnt know I dont need actual key in object for v-model.... It works without having key in object for done

Comment: I added to the array of JSON objects in my AJAX call: 
`for (var i in restData) { restData[i].done = false; }`

Answer (score 1):

Simply just add `done: false` in todos and add `v-model="todo.done"` to input in `v-for`.

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/82srdLc5/)

Differences from your code:

```
// added `done`
todos: [
  { done: false, text: "Learn JavaScript"},
  { done: false, text: "Learn Vue"},
  { done: false, text: "Play around in JSFiddle"},
  { done: false, text: "Build something awesome"}
]
```

```
<!-- added `v-model="todo.done"` -->
<input v-model="todo.done" type="checkbox">
```

Comment: How to add `done: false` to your data (array of JSON objects):
`for (var i in data) { data[i]['done'] = false; }`
OR
`for (var i in data) { data[i].done = false; }`

Comment: Both ways should work. Btw, it's better to create a computed method in your component with mutated (modified) array and use array's map function. Something like this `computed: { 
todosWithMark() { return this.todos.map(todo => ({ ...todo, done: false})) } }` and use it.